# Stack Overflow No captcha box is shown in the human verification page

Tags: support, captcha

I'm using an approved browsers like Chrome and Safari. But in the human verification page, the Captcha box is not displaying for me.

What should I do?

[image: human-verification page]

Comment: Disable your browser extension that is blocking scripts, e.g. "NoScript", or some other fancy extension, and you will see it just fine.